# How to Silent Camera Click While Take Photo Using Java ME Code

Tags: mobile, java-me, camera, midp

I am developing a Java ME Application. My Application take photos at a regular Interval. My Application is working fine. Here Whenever My Application click the photo, It creates The Camera "click" Sound.

How Can I Make This Sound Silent ?

Comment: The click sound may be there to prevent applications from spying on the user without the user's knowledge.  If that's the case, then it may be intentionally difficult or impossible to avoid the click sound.

Comment: No Jeremy, It's not for spying purpose, it for Mobile Using as CCTV Camera purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a good trick, how to disable a sound of a shutter, with playing of a tone. You have to set a short sleep time, for initializing tone playing. So here is my code:

```
try 
{
Manager.playTone(1, 100, 1);
Thread.sleep(30);
data = videoControl.getSnapshot("encoding=jpeg&width=600&height=800");
} 
catch (MediaException e) {}
catch (InterruptedException e) {}
```

Comment: @ James, Is this working fine? AFAIK, Basically `Manager.playTone` generate the Tone. I dont think this is mute the camera click sound.

Comment: Yes Bharath, Its works as Playing another sound while the "click" sounds occurs. So its works like overriding the "click" sound.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK you can't. Because there is no API available to access the camera settings. You can disable the camera sound manually on camera settings. But some mobiles (like Nokia N78, N79, ETC...) could not allow to mute the camera sound for some security purpose. :)

Comment: Just to expand a bit on this: Java ME can do as much as it's allowed by the hardware, as long as it complies with the spec. Knowing your camera/mobile model may help looking for a special API, but this doesn't mean it'll be generic, though.

Comment: ok fine, But if My Application is singed then also it is not possible to mute it ?

Comment: Yeah... Because there is no API allow to access them.

Comment: you can say bharath instead of sir. :)